# Increase speed of Ntile function in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am running the Ntile function 4 times over 4 partition variables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 AS
Select*,

ntile(10) over (partition by A, B,C,D order by var1) as dec_1,
ntile(10) over (partition by A, B,C,D order by var2) as dec_2,
ntile(10) over (partition by A, B,C,D order by var3) as dec_3,
ntile(10) over (partition by A, B,C,D order by var4) as dec_4

From Table1
```

The table has approx 400 million rows currently the operation either runs really slowly or fails.  Would performance be improved if I order `Table1` by `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` before running this query??

Comment: There is no such thing as "ordering table1" because tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, that will not work.

Comment: So is the only option adjusting configurations?

Comment: . . I can't think of anything off-hand.  But check something:  is `row_number()` faster than `ntile()`?  Also, it might be much faster if the table is *partitioned* by A, B, and C.

Comment: @gordon-linoff AFAIK Hive tables can be bucketed and **sorted**  (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable), albeit partially. @te-time partitioning and clustering Table1 (if you can enforce it) should improve the performance. Sorting would be more of an issue because of your multiple `order by`s.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try.  Do you think running 8 queries in my case in parallel  for the combinations of the A,B,C  group variables and only partitioning on D in each case and take a union of the results would be a faster option?